# How to turn of [Fn] key changing keyboard language in Monterey

Tags: keyboard, monterey, internationalization, language

I just upgraded to Monterey and am being driven a bit spare by accidental language switching resulting from the side of my hand hitting the `fn` key on my Magic Keyboard. Is there a way to disable this? All I can see in the keyboard settings is a reference to Caplocks and Alt+Space or something like that (both currently disabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In system preferences > keyboard > keyboard there should be a place where you can set Fn to Do Nothing.  Note that Globe and Fn are the same key.